# Exposed filter as dependent dropdown?

Tags: views

Is it possible to create a view with exposed filter similar to the image given, where location field is a taxonomy term and rest of it are content types with location field as term reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Views Dependent Filter Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) integrates this functionality with views

> Allows the presence of exposed filters on a view to be controlled by
>   values in another exposed filter. Dependent filters are hidden when
>   not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed
>   form is submitted.